# Redirecting a URL With # character, possible?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I think I may have painted myself int a corner. I used to have a contact page with a standard permalink /contact/.

I changed to a popup contactform accessible from every page with the anchor tag #maincontactform.

I can create links   works fine.

But... how do I redirect old backlinks which use /contact to the new format?

You can't do a MOD Rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule /contact #maincontactform [R=301,L]
```

This seems to expand to /%23maincontactform

Any suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` will automatically escape special characters into their hex-form. If you don't want this, you have to explicitly tell it to not do that with the `NE` flag. Besides that, remember that in per-directory-context, such as a .htaccess file, the part that you match with your regex doesn't begin with a slash. `http://example.com/contact` should therefore be matched with `^contact/?$`.

```
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ #maincontactform [R=301,NE,L]
```

See [the documentation for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [the NE flag especially](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne)

Comment: Is the backtick in your RewriteRule a typo or is that necessary? If necessary, what does that do?

Comment: That's a typo. I have a keyboard with delayed accents and apparently I had still one under the caret, but didn't notice that.

Comment: Cool. Works a treat. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The [`NE` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) will prevent mod_rewrite from escaping the hash.

```
RewriteRule /contact #maincontactform [R=301,NE,L]
```